# Indices issue in Blender->three.js exporting

Tags: python, json, three.js, blender

I'm trying to export my 3d model from blender to three.js using the json extension. However, I bet there is a problem with the exporting script: it looks like the indices are messed up, thus webgl can't read them and displays no geometry.
To be specific, here's the indices for a simple cube:

```
[41,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,41,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,41,0,4,5,1,0,4,7,8,0,4,7,1,41,1,5,6,2,1,9,6,2,1,7,6,2,41,2,6,7,3,2,6,5,3,2,6,5,3,41,4,0,3,7,4,0,3,5,4,0,3,5]
```

The numbers are obviously exceeding the real index count, which ranges in 0-7.

Just in case, here's the code used for parsing:

```
function loadTeapot() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "teapotprova.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            handleLoadedTeapot(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

Everyone else having the same issue?

*edit: the script i'm using for json exporting is [threejs blender export](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)